# Accessing Custom Configurations in NUnit class

Tags: c#, app-config, custom-configuration

I'm really banging my head onto this one. I can't make the Custom Configuration to work with NUnit. It kept on failing to read the configuration file. I'm currently making a logging class.

I followed carefully this article: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx

placed the references in the Unit test class App.Config, still everything failed.

Is there some sort of a magic setting to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define custom configuration in correct config file, see the following reference:

http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/08/nunit-app-config-files-its-all-about-the-nunit-file/